# The right form of Null /Blank for Python and R when storing data in the database?

Tags: sql-server, r, python-3.x, data-science

I am preparing a data set, using a ETL tool. Later I will export all the data in to SQL server table. Then the data will be consumed by R and Python (based on the developer choice) and Tableau for Visual. I would like to know how I should handle the Null and blank. I want to have them in one format when storing in the SQL server.
For Example This is a table:

```
ID      Title  Active
KO1003  [Null]  [Null]
KO1014  [Null]  1
KO1024          
KO1055  [Null]  1
```

So my target is to treat the `Null` and `blank` with one unique method so that It ease the work for both R or Python developer when reading data from database. I searched for couple of resources, but there is no clear situation like this.
Thanks